# CSS element won't work correctly

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I been trying to apply a element to a simple text and make it align to the right:
The color and font size seems to work correctly, so I know its working half right, but whenever i use text-align. It just doesn't work. But when I use the auto-style it works. It's so buggy, I have no clue why it's doing this. And it's really annoying.

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">   
 <link href="App_Themes/MasterPage/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"      
 />
 </asp:Content>

<p3>VIDEO SECTION</p3>
```

here is the css code:
     p3{
     text-align: right;
     color: #FF0066;
     }

I have this set up as masterpage with a content page. 
It seems to work when i use an inline style, but not an external one.

Comment: Check whether the element is seen as block or inline .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be because the width of your p3 is not enough to align your text to the right of its container, cause the p3 itself has the same width of the text that it contains.

Try using a `display:block;` and `width:100%;`

Comment: Also if you 'inspect element ' in chrome you'll see the p tag only is a small area before you set width to 100%. After you'll notice the tag stretches across the page and thus the text will move to the right end of the p tag.